# Hibernate & Apache Struts2 - Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, hibernate, session, struts2

I am trying to learn about Hibernate and Apache Struts2 and have run into a problem. I keep getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Transaction not successfully started on line
com.dao.struts.UserSession.list(UserSession.java:58)
```

Hibernate Helper Class:

```
package com.dao.util;

//imports here

public class HibHelper 
{
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSession();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static SessionFactory buildSession()
    {
        try {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void close() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

UserSession class

```
package com.dao.struts;

//imports here

public class UserSession extends HibHelper
{
    public Data add(Data user)
    {
        Session session = HibHelper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    public Data delete(Long id)
    {
        Session session = HibHelper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Data user = (Data) session.load(Data.class, id);

        if(user != null)
            session.delete(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    public List<Data> list()
    {
        Session session = HibHelper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Data> userList = null;

        try {
            userList = (List<Data>) session.createQuery("from Data").list();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        return userList;
    }
}
```

It is saying the error is in the `list()` method in `UserSession.java` on this line: `session.getTransaction().commit();` It is adding to the database perfectly fine. I just can't seem to output it. My database name is `mo` and table name is `USERS`. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your transaction is already committed to the database. Can you just check if the transaction is already committed ([wasCommitted()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#wasCommitted())) and if not do the commit ?

```
if(!session.getTransaction.wasCommitted()){
session.getTransaction.commit()
}
```

---

And did you forget to open/close brackets of `if` properly. Is it not the below code that should be used?

```
 if(user != null){
            session.delete(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

---

From what I think of the issue, the below code should be working

```
      public List<Data> list() {
    Session session = HibHelper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Data> userList = null;

    try {
        userList = (List<Data>) session.createQuery("from Data").list();

                if(!session.getTransaction.wasCommitted()){
                    session.getTransaction.commit()
                    }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    session.close();
    return userList;
}
```

Comment: I added that to the list() method replacing `session.getTransaction().commit();`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Nice catch with the delete method. However, the other problem still stands.

Comment: Thank you so much! I put that if statement after the try/catch, which is why it didn't work before.